# How to show ProgressDialog after AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I am having trouble with an alert dialog that I cannot hide.

when the user press a button I show a dialog that is created with this code :

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.enterPassword)                
            .setView(textEntryView)          
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            String password = pwdText.getText().toString();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            processUserAction(password,targetUri);
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                    
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            }                
                        })             
            .
            create();
```

There are some heavy operations performed in the 'processUserAction' method, and inside it I am using an AysncTask that displays a ProgressDialog.

The problem I am having is that the dialog prompting for the password never goes of the screen (I have tried with dismiss(), cancel()). 
I guess it stays there until the onClick method is finished.

So, my question is how to close that AlertDialog, so I can show the ProgressDialog?

Another approach I have been trying  is to set a DismissListener in the AlertDialog and calling the heavy operations from there, but I have had no luck ( it didn't get called ).

**EDIT**: Adding AsyncTask code

```
public class BkgCryptOperations extends AsyncTask<File,Void,Integer>{

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(File... files) {
        if (files!=null && files.length > 0){
            File source = files[0];
            File target = files[1];
            return cryptAction.process(source,password, target);
        }

        return Constants.RetCodeKO;
    }

    CryptAction cryptAction;
    String password;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    public BkgCryptOperations (CryptAction cryptAction,String password,ProgressDialog progressDialog){
        this.cryptAction=cryptAction;
        this.password=password;
        this.progressDialog=progressDialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (progressDialog!=null){
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer i) {
        if (progressDialog!=null){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you calling dialog.show()? of course, you must be calling that to display a dialog. If yes, can you modify the code for more clarity.

Comment: yes, I am calling dialog.show() right after creating it. Which part do you want me to clarify?. I think I am having problems with the setPositiveButton onClickListener part.

Comment: have you tried defining a static AlertDialog in your activity and then dismissing it directly by its name from the onClick() event (instead of using that DialogInterface instance)?

Comment: you mean having a reference to the AlertDialog in the Activity and executing dismiss on that reference, right? I'll check and update. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a excample how I do it:

```
public void daten_remove_on_click(View button) {
        // Nachfragen
        if (spinadapter.getCount() > 0) {
            AlertDialog Result = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_data_remove_titel))
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_data_remove_text))
                    .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.dialog_no),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(
                                        DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    // Nicht löschen
                                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                                }
                            })
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_yes),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(
                                        DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    String _quellenName = myCursor.getString(1);
                                    deleteQuellenRecord(_quellenName);
                                    zuletztGelöscht = _quellenName;
                                }
                            }).show();
        } else {
            // Keine Daten mehr vorhanden
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Daten.this,
                    getString(R.string.dialog_data_remove_empty),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code of deleteQuellenRecord:

```
private void deleteQuellenRecord(String _quellenName) {
        String DialogTitel = getString(R.string.daten_delete_titel);
        String DialogText = getString(R.string.daten_delete_text);
        // Dialogdefinition Prograssbar
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean onSearchRequested() {
                return false;
            }
        };
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setTitle(DialogTitel);
        dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        dialog.setMessage(DialogText);
        // set the progress to be horizontal
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        // reset the bar to the default value of 0
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        // set the maximum value
        dialog.setMax(4);
        // display the progressbar
        increment = 1;
        dialog.show();
        // Thread starten
        new Thread(new MyDeleteDataThread(_quellenName)) {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Datensatz löschen
                    myDB.execSQL("DELETE ... ');");
                    progressHandler
                            .sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                    myDB.execSQL("DELETE ...);");
                    // active the update handler
                    progressHandler
                            .sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                    myDB.execSQL("DELETE ...;");
                    // active the update handler
                    progressHandler
                            .sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                    // Einstellung speichern
                    try {
                        settings.edit().putString("LetzteQuelle", "-1")
                                .commit();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        settings.edit().putString("LetzteQuelle", "").commit();
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Wait dialog beenden
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Log.e("Glutenfrei Viewer",
                            "Error in activity MAIN - remove data", ex); // log
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // error
                }
                // Wait dialog beenden
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        }.start();
        this.onCreate(null);
    }
```

Wiht Async Task I do it this way:

```
private class RunningAlternativSearch extends
            AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {


        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchResult.this) {
            @Override
            public boolean onSearchRequested() {
                return false;
            }
        };



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            alternativeSucheBeendet = false;
            String DialogTitel = getString(R.string.daten_wait_titel);
            DialogText = getString(R.string.dialog_alternativ_text);
            DialogZweiteChance = getString(R.string.dialog_zweite_chance);
            DialogDritteChance = getString(R.string.dialog_dritte_chance);
            sucheNach = getString(R.string.dialog_suche_nach);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setTitle(DialogTitel);
            dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            dialog.setMessage(DialogText);
            dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    cancleBarcodeWorker();
                    if (alternativeSucheBeendet==false){
                        // Activity nur beenden wenn die Suche
                        // nicht beendet wurde, also vom User abgebrochen
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SearchResult.this, SearchResult.this
                                .getString(R.string.toast_suche_abgebrochen),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                        myDB.close();
                        SearchResult.this.finish();
                    }
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }


        ...
```

Comment: Same as Aaron proposal, I'll try that and update, but at first glance I cannot see the difference, as the onClink method will still being executed while processing the heavy operations. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have updatet the answer. deleteQuellenRecord is a long running task with showing a progress bar. The strange thing is that I never call Result.dismiss() or Result.cancle() but the Dialog dissapear and the progress bar comes to front. Perhaps it helps to delete the line dialog.dismiss() or change it to cancle()

Comment: I didn't have the dismiss() or cacncel() before, I just put it there because I read that they were supossed to work. How did you execute the long runnning tasks in the deleteQuellenRecord? using AsyncTask? or just creating your own thread?

Comment: Added an excample for async task. Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the example, I am changing it to use the Thread approach instead of the AsyncTask, as also has been proposed by licabl. I'll update when I can test it, but it will take some time, as I cannot do it right now.

Comment: It worked with the thread approach. I will still investigate why it is not working with the AsyncTask, but thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the code for processUserAction(..)? There is no need to include the dismiss. 
I did something very similar and had no problems... 
Here's the code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Export data.\nContinue?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String file = getObra().getNome();
                            d = new ProgressDialog(MenuActivity.this);
                            d.setTitle("Exporting...");
                            d.setMessage("please wait...");
                            d.setIndeterminate(true);
                            d.setCancelable(false);
                            d.show();
                            export(file);
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

In export(file) I open the thread:

```
private void export(final String file) {


    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ExportData ede = new ExportData(
                        getApplicationContext(), getPmo().getId(),
                        file);
                ede.export();
                handlerMessage("Done!!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handlerMessage(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("ERROR!!!" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

In handlerMessage I dismiss the progressDialog and show the final message. 
Hope it helps you.

Comment: I can add the processUserAction method, but it will only confuse things. It works fine, but during its 4-5 seconds of execution I only see the AlertDialog on top of the app (that's the problem I have, it is not too friendly). It is also unclickable in this time. The approach you are suggesting is different than the AsyncTask I am using, I'll try it and update. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a listener outside of the AlertDialog, to abstract out the logic within the OnClickListener for the positive button.  That way, the listener can be notified, and the AlertDialog will be dismissed immediately.  Then, whatever processing of the user's input from the AlertDialog can take place independently of the AlertDialog.  I'm not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this or not, but it's worked well for me in the past.

As far as I can tell, I don't see any obvious problems with your AsyncTask code.

```
public interface IPasswordListener {
    public void onReceivePassword(String password);
}

IPasswordListener m_passwordListener = new IPasswordListener {
    @Override
    public void onReceivePassword(String password) {
        processUserAction(password,targetUri);
    }
}

public void showPasswordDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.enterPassword);
    builder.setView(textEntryView);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            m_passwordListener.onReceivePassword(pwdText.getText().toString());
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: I'll try that and update, but at first glance I cannot see the difference, as the onClink method will still being executed while processing the heavy operations. Thanks for the suggestion.